# how to create django web page similar to admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a beginner in django and i want to create a new web page which i can edit and add to a database model like the admin site page but this will be in the website to enable the user to control it and i can extend my **base.html** page in it, I search for it and i didn't find a simple solution like admin base site that enable me to control the models, i tried to send all objects of this model in the context but i cant add or edit it in the database model, just i can view it only.

can any one help me? thanks.

This is my **models.py** for this web  page:

```
from django.db import models

class Email(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.TextField()
    from_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    reply_to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    body_html = models.TextField()
    status= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,default='waiting')  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.to_email

class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
    template_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    from_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    reply_to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    body_html = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.template_name
```

my **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import  render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from survey.models import *
from user_management.models import Candidate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django import forms
import settings

from emailtemplates import models
from email_sender.models import *

from report.pdf import DrawarmPDF,send_pdf_in_email

from decorators import superuser_required



@login_required
@superuser_required()
def home(request):

  query_results = EmailTemplate.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('emailtemplates/emailtemplates.html', 
                              {"query_results":query_results},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add action for POST method:

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
    #            ^^^^^^
    #    do save action code

    query_results = EmailTemplate.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('emailtemplates/emailtemplates.html', 
                              {"query_results":query_results},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And you may use forms for save action, more details here: [forms view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view)

And it be good to read about form class view [class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: Thanks for you i will check them.